# How can I remove title from transparent, frameless window

Tags: vue.js, electron

I'm developing an Electron+Vue app on Windows 10 (generated though vue-cli and [this](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue) template).

At the moment I've managed to display a transparent window. As soon as the frame loose focus, a title at the top of the page appears.

What I've figured out is that the title is the one set in `index.ejs`.

If I remove it, the title appears anyway (label: Electron)

Do you know how I can remove that?
[image: screen]

This is the configuration of the browser window:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 200,
    useContentSize: true,
    width: 200,
    transparent: true,
    titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
    frame: false,
    resizable: false,
    webPreferences: {
      overlayScrollbars: true
    }
  })
  mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false)
  mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true)
  mainWindow.setIgnoreMouseEvents(false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is the reason:

- https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11849
- https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12033

Fix will arrive in 1.8.3 or 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
mainApp = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        resizable: false,
        alwaysOnTop: true,
        frame: false,
        focusable: true,
        minimizable: false,
        maximizable: false,
        closable: false,
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        transparent: true,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
             overlayScrollbars: true
        }
});
mainApp.name ='give a name';
mainApp.setMenu(null);
mainApp.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true);
```